# header("Location: ".$session->referrer);

Tags: php, session

newbie question sorry.

I've downloaded a script to test and found that a new page/tab opens after submitting the form.  I prefer it to open in the same window.

I'm presuming its this line that it's affecting it but not sure, any advice is good.

```
header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
```

the form

```
<form  class="form-signin" action="process.php" method="POST"> 
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>

    <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $form->value("user"); ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <?php echo $form->error("user"); ?>

    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $form->value("pass"); ?>"class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <?php echo $form->error("pass"); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if($form->value("remember") != ""){ echo "checked"; } ?>></div><div class="col-xs-6">Remember me [<a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password?</a>]</div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="sublogin" value="1">
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

and the process

```
class Process
{
   /* Class constructor */
   function Process(){
      global $session;
      /* User submitted login form */
      if(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
         $this->procLogin();
      }
      /* User submitted registration form */
      else if(isset($_POST['subjoin'])){
         $this->procRegister();
      }

        /* User submitted registration form */
      else if(isset($_POST['member_subjoin'])){
         $this->procMemberRegister();
      }

          /* User submitted registration form */
      else if(isset($_POST['master_subjoin'])){
         $this->procMasterRegister();
      }

          /* User submitted registration form */
      else if(isset($_POST['agent_subjoin'])){
         $this->procAgentRegister();
      }

      /* User submitted forgot password form */
      else if(isset($_POST['subforgot'])){
         $this->procForgotPass();
      }
      /* User submitted edit account form */
      else if(isset($_POST['subedit'])){
         $this->procEditAccount();
      }
      /**
       * The only other reason user should be directed here
       * is if he wants to logout, which means user is
       * logged in currently.
       */
      else if($session->logged_in){
         $this->procLogout();
      }
      /**
       * Should not get here, which means user is viewing this page
       * by mistake and therefore is redirected.
       */
       else{
          header("Location: main.php");
       }
   }
```

Comment: give us a the full script please

Comment: What´s the HTML code for the form?

Answer (score 1):

if `<form>` tag has a `target` attribute, and its value is `_blank` it submits on a new page.

Please refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp).

Comment: thanks Arda, that has pointed me in the right direction. The forms action points to another another page, in the other page, it directs it back to the form page. Is there a way to post back to the orginal page without loading another?

index.php -> process.php -> index.php

Comment: You have to edit the PHP script for that. You can keep the url that would be redirected to in the part of url or get it in the session (which I wouldn't prefer by the way). I can't say much without seeing the script in this case. Pure HTML cannot handle it.